# Why does inferring of generic type does not work here?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following classes:

```java
interface MyS<T extends MyT<S, T>, S extends MyS<T, S>> {
}
interface MyT<S extends MyS<T, S>, T extends MyT<S, T>> {
}
public class MySImpl implements MyS<MyTImpl, MySImpl> {
}
public class MyTImpl implements MyT<MySImpl, MyTImpl> {
}
```

I can build the following testcase which compiles and runs successfully without any warning:

```java
public class STTest {

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    createInstance(MyTImpl.class);
  }

  public static<T extends MyT<S, T>, S extends MyS<T, S>> void createInstance(
      final Class<? extends MyT<S, T>> beanClass) throws Exception {

    final MyT<S, T> bean = beanClass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

OK, fine. But I expected that this would have the identical effect:

```java
public class STTest {

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    createInstance(MyTImpl.class);
  }

  public static<T extends MyT<S, T>, S extends MyS<T, S>> void createInstance(
      final Class<T> beanClass) throws Exception {

    final T bean = beanClass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

However, this is a compile error:

> invalid inferred types for S; inferred type does not conform to
>   declared bound(s) inferred: MySImpl bound(s): MyS

Why is this?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that the behaviour is compiler dependent. I used the OpenJDK 1.6 compiler (javac 1.6.0_27) for compiling to code. And it breaks. However:

- The OpenJDK 1.7 compiler (javac 1.7.0_21) and
- The Oracle 1.6 compiler (javac 1.6.0_37)

both work fine on the second example.

However: Is this a bug in the OpenJDK 1.6 compiler or is this an ambiguity in the Java language specification?

Comment: I can run your code and I do not get the compilation error...

Comment: Same here. Only compilation error in missing bracket at your interface declaration.

Comment: I'll add that it also compiles with the Eclipse compiler for Java 7.

Comment: @darijan: I tried switching the compiler and *wham*... it works. See update in my question.@davechu: fixed.

Comment: What would be the use of such circularly referential generic interfaces? It seems more confusing than it would be worth...

Answer (score 3):

The argument type doesn't mention S in any way in the second example. The compiler is telling you that it therefore can't infer it.

To elaborate. In the first example, you ask for a `Class<? extends MyT<S, T>>`. In `test()`, you give it a `Class<MyTImpl>`. As the compiler checks the bounds, it matches `MyT<S, T>` against `MyTImpl` and finds that `MyTImpl` implements `MyT<MySImpl, MyTImpl>`, so it can infer `MySImpl` for `S` and `MyTImpl` for `T` by simply placing those two things alongside.

Then it checks the constraints on `S` and `T` for `MySImpl` and `MyTImpl`, which succeeds.

In the second example, you ask for a `Class<T>`. The compiler sees `Class<MyTImpl>`, infers `MyTImpl` for `T`, and is done. Failing to infer `S`, it errors out.

Constraint checking for `T`, which could provide the information what `S` is, doesn't happen.

Comment: True, this doesn't happen. But why? In the meantime I figured out that the behaviour is compiler dependent. So is obviously IS possible.